# Blocking inside RxJava map fails to complete

Tags: rx-java, deadlock, blocking

The following (bad way of using RxJava 1.2.4) code fails to unblock and never finishes.

```
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.computation();
Observable.range(0, 100).map(i -> {
    System.out.println("onNext " + i);
    return Observable.just(i).subscribeOn(scheduler).toBlocking().single();
}).subscribeOn(scheduler).toBlocking().subscribe();
System.out.println("finished");
```

If you change the first line to a fixed thread pool it finishes.

```
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8));
```

What is special about the computation scheduler that makes the first example not work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Do not do that

Please pay attention to what documentation says about computation scheduler:

> This can be used for event-loops, processing callbacks and other computational work. **Do not perform IO-bound work on this scheduler**.

They wanted to say: **Do not perform any blocking activities on this scheduler**.

So what you are doing is illegal, but it serves as a good demonstration.

### Why dead lock happens

The same dead lock occurs in RxJava 2 (2.0.4 at this time).

It happens due to the way `computation` scheduler is implemented. It creates fixed number of single-thread workers (the number of these is the number of CPU cores; 4 in my case). The way it assigns tasks to these workers is simple **round-robin**. Now let's see what tasks get assigned to which workers in your example.

- worker 1 <- `subscribe()` call invokes a loop to generate integers in `range`; note that this task does not finish untill all values get passed downstream
- worker 2 <- `just(0)...toBlocking().single()` for the first generated integer; this one completes immediately without real blocking as the value is already available
- worker 3 <- `just(1)...toBlocking().single()` for the second generated integer; this one completes immediately
- worker 4 <- `just(2)...toBlocking().single()` for the third generated integer; this one completes immediately

At this moment we have *worker 1* still busy doing the `range` loop, *workers 2-4* idle. Next task comes in from the loop, it gets assigned to *worker1* according to *round-robin*:

- worker 1 <- `just(3)...toBlocking().single()` for the fourth generated integer; this one gets queued, while *worker 1* loop is stuck waiting to its result. Here is the dead lock.

`FixedThreadPool` scheduler does not lock because it assigns tasks to available thread, not in round-robin fashion. Just make sure it has more than 1 thread.

### Blocking is evil

Generally you should avoid blocking actions in Rx pipeline. Rx provides great tools to perform asynchronous tasks without blocking. Instead of `map` you can use `flatMap`, for example:

```
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.computation();
Observable.range(0, 100).flatMap(i -> {
    System.out.println("onNext " + i);
    return Observable.just(i).subscribeOn(scheduler);
}).subscribeOn(scheduler).toBlocking().subscribe();
System.out.println("finished");
```

This will work even with single threaded scheduler.

Instead of `Observable.just(i)` you can invoke real asynchronous tasks like this `Observable.fromFuture(asyncService(i))`.

Use `concatMap` instead of `flatMap` to preserve ordering of items, if this is essential.

Comment: Yes. I know it's bad but my application is hundreds of thousands of lines of Rx code maintained by 100s of people. If anyone adds one bit of blocking the whole app fails to lunch without any error that this deadlock has occurred. Why does the computation Scheduler lock?

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell I thought I described it in great detail in my answer.

Comment: Bugs happen just saying "don't write bugs" is not an acceptable answer.

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell You cannot fix a bug without actially fixing it. I explained you why it happens, so now you know where to search and how to fix.

Comment: Yes. I know what happens. That is why I was able to find and reduce the code down to something so small. But to say it easy to search for is incorrect because there is no indication where it is happening. I was lucky this time but I've seen others just throw up there hands and just do whatever it takes to makes it work and move on. I'm more pissed that there isn't a clear error message then it not working. Even dumping all the threads doesn't help narrow it down. If it's not possible to give an error message then I would prefer it to not lock like the fixed size thread pool.

Comment: Great answer! It should be accepted as it fully answers the question.

Comment: I think you need to consider that it's not the RxJava library's responsibility to guard against any possible misuse. I believe it would be an never-ending endeavor trying to achieve that. In this case it's clear that it's the client code's fault that it uses blocking code on a scheduler where it shouldn't. @YaroslavStavnichiy answered the question perfectly.

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell You _can_ dump threads to see what the problem is. Just check the stack trace of each thread to see what blocking call is stuck.

https://gist.github.com/joshallenit/9f9271474d62d206174ae580147e876f